# Regular expression for a custom tokeniser on elasticsearch

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a custom tokeniser for elasticsearch to parse tweet:

Let's say I have this text:

```
"This is a test!! @test_twitter #testForLife"
```

I want to generate the following token:

```
["This", "is", "a", "test!!", "@test_twitter", "#testForLife"]
```

To do so I have come up with the following regex that I test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dT6dK8/7):

```
(\w*\S*[\S*])
```

It's seems to work well.

The problem is that I need a Java regex for my analyser, so I convert it using regex101 and I got the following:

```
(\\w*\\S*[\\S*])
```

I test it on the following website  http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html but it doesn't seem to catch anything, I tried it on elasticsearch:

```
PUT my_index
{ "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "tweeter_analyser_nlp" :{
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "tweeter_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "tweeter_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "(\\w*\\S*[\\S*])"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tweet": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "term_vector": "yes",
          "analyzer" : "tweeter_analyser_nlp"
         },
         "fullname": {
          "type": "text",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "analyzer" : "tweeter_analyser_nlp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it doesn't catch anything as well:

```
GET my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "tweeter_analyser_nlp",
  "text": "A test"
}
```

It returns me:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": " ",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Is my regex in Java wrong if yes what would be the good Java regex?

Or does the problem come from somewhere else?

Comment: It seems you just need `"\\S+"` to match chunks of 1 or more non-whitespace symbols.

Comment: I hope you copied the original RegEx, not the "Java version", as this is what **RegexPlanet** waits...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Ok you solved my problem concerning the **RegexPlanet** problem, I was indeed feeding it with the "Java version" but elastic search is still not tokenizing properly

Comment: Use the same pattern there, too...

Comment: What if you just use `"type": "whitespace"` without any regex patterns?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Yeah it works! Can you write down the answer to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the whitespace tokenizer type:

```
"tokenizer": {
    "tweeter_tokenizer": {
      "type": "whitespace"
    }
  }
```